# Termux write to SD card

Tags: sd-card, permissions, termux

Android 5

Termux 0.54

Not rooted, no wish to

```
$ pwd
/storage/sdcard1
$ id
uid=10096(u0_a96) gid=10096(u0_a96) groups=1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3003(inet),9997(everybody),50096(all_a96)
$ ls -l python
total 0
$ ls -dl python
drwxrwx---    2 root     sdcard_r     32768 Sep 23 22:10 python
```

So according to permissions, I should be able to write to the python folder. But creating a file gives permission denied.

I have seen the platform.xml solution but can't edit the file.

I would like to write to card then easy to move card and files between machines.

Regards
John

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with SELinux. What does `ls -ld /storage/sdcard1/` show though? Also have you enabled the storage permission in the app settings of Termux?

Comment: This is something Google is to blame. From Android 5 onwards, there have been even more restrictions placed on the external SD. Apps are now expected to make use of a so-called `DocumentProvider` interface, as to ask the user for the permission to operate on the SD card. As you may infer by the above, there is no way to manually grant this permission if it is not requested, but to have root privileges and install Xposed, or to have a custom recovery, init.d support and flash a `.zip` to allow SD card access to any app.

Comment: @TomYan Sadly, as you can see from my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183756/152843), the **Storage** permission only affects `/storage/emulated/0` (`/storage/sdcard0` on Lollipop).

Answer (score 6):

Use `termux-setup-storage` to setup your storage. 
See https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage for instructions and more information.  Write data will be enabled in the Termux private folder on external storage through `~/storage/external` which is a link to `Android/data/com.termux/files/` on your external SD card.

Comment: This is for android 6. As I mentioned, I have android 5.

Comment: Android 5 support was dropped in January 2020